# Euclidean norm and matrix questions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n×m$ real matrix and define $\vert A \vert_{2}^{2}={\rm tr}(A^tA)$.

1)Show that $|A|_2$ is the Euclidean norm of $A$, when we view $A$ as a vector in $R^{nm}$ by stacking the columns of $A$.

2)Find the cosine of the angle between
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
 1& 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$, and $B=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0\\ 
 1& 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

(Here what stacking the columns of $A$ means?)

Comment: About 2), $cos\theta =\frac{a\cdot b}{||a||||b||}$, is $a\cdot b$ here 1*4+1*0+1*0+1*1+0*0+1*0?

Comment: @i_a_n: yes. Look at ncmathsadist's answer -or mine. Without looking at matrices as vectors, a dot product on matrices can be defined as $A\cdot B = \mathrm{tr}(A^tB)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$(A^t A)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m (A^t)_{ik}A_{kj} = \sum_{k=1}^m A_{ki}A_{kj}$$
Now compute the trace.
$${\rm tr}(A^tA) = \sum_{i=1}^n (A^tA)_{ii} = \sum_{i-1}^n\sum_{k=1}^m A_{ki}^2,$$
which gives you the Euclidean norm of an $mn$-dimensional vector.

That answers question 1..

Comment: But when m>n, $(A^t)_{ik}$ can't reach $(A^t)_{im}$

Comment: Ican't understand why $(A^t A)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m (A^t)_{ik}A_{kj}$

Answer (score 1):

This: if

$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1  &  3  &  5  \\
2  &  4  &  6
\end{pmatrix}
$$

then, as a vector of $\mathbb{R}^{3\cdot 2}$, we view it like

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
2  \\
3  \\
4  \\
5  \\
6
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and the square of its norm is

$$
\vert A \vert_2^2 =
\mathrm{tr}
\left[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1  &  2  \\
3  &  4  \\
5  &  6
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1  &  3  &  5  \\
2  &  4  &  6
\end{pmatrix}
\right]
=
\mathrm{tr}
\begin{pmatrix}
1+4  &  11  &  17  \\
11 &  9+16  &  39  \\
17 &  39  &  25 + 36
\end{pmatrix}
=
1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 + 36 
$$

Which happens to be the same as

$$
(1,2,3,4,5,6)
\begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
2  \\
3  \\
4  \\
5  \\
6
\end{pmatrix}
=
1 + 4 + 9 + 16+ 25 + 36  \ .
$$